# Properly display JSON in table angular

Tags: angularjs, json, html-table, display

I have an API which return me a JSON array:

```
{"i":11,"j":12,"iterationNumber":9,"results":[12,6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]}
```

How can I make a table in angular, so the data is displayed correctly?
Currently I have this:

[image: current table]

My html code is:

```
<table class="table table-striped " ng-show="tableR">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>i Value</th>
            <th>j Value</th>
            <th>iternation Number Value</th>
            <th>results</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
            <td>{{x.i}}</td>
            <td>{{x.j}}</td>
            <td>{{x.iterationNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{x.results}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Can you help me fix the last column, so instead of displaying all the values in one row, make it display it into different rows?

Comment: results is an array, you need to repeat it like you did with data

Comment: @AngelSilva Did you have any luck getting this to work?  Can I help in any other way?

Comment: @TimHarker thank you very much, it worked flawlessly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be closer to what Angel Silva is after.

[image]

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>i Value</th>
          <th>j Value</th>
          <th>iternation Number Value</th>
          <th>results</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ng-repeat="x in data">
        <tr ng-repeat="r in x.results">
          <td>{{x.i}}</td>
          <td>{{x.j}}</td>
          <td>{{x.iterationNumber}}</td>
          <td>{{r}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

JavaScript/AngularJS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{"i":11,"j":12,"iterationNumber":9,"results":[12,6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]}];
});
```

Here's a link to a working Plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/NrnFI17P932KckzXRcF4?p=preview

Comment: No worries.  Do you mind making it as the"accepted" answer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Use a second `ng-repeat` within an `<ul>` (unordered list):

```
<table class="table table-striped " ng-show="tableR">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>i Value</th>
        <th>j Value</th>
        <th>iternation Number Value</th>
        <th>results</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
        <td>{{x.i}}</td>
        <td>{{x.j}}</td>
        <td>{{x.iterationNumber}}</td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="r in x.results">
                    {{ r }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of `columns` which could be named as `columns`. Loop over columns to render `td`'s data with current `x`

**Controller**

```
$scope.data = {"i":11,"j":12,"iterationNumber":9,"results":[12,6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]};
$scope.columns = Object.key($scope.data)
```

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{x[column]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**array.join()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to join all the elements of an array into a string.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.tableR = true;
    $scope.data = [{
    "i":11,
    "j":12,
    "iterationNumber":9,
    "results":[12,6,3,10,5,16,8,4,2,1]
    }];
});
```

```css
tr,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped " ng-show="tableR">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>i Value</th>
            <th>j Value</th>
            <th>iternation Number Value</th>
            <th>results</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
            <td>{{x.i}}</td>
            <td>{{x.j}}</td>
            <td>{{x.iterationNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{x.results.join()}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```