# How to Properly Display JSON Data from MongoDB in Angular Material Table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express, angular-material

**Desire**

I'm attempting to pull data from MongoDB and display it in an Angular Material Table.

**Issue**

While I am able to see the results of my MongoDB call when logging to the console/terminal, the Chrome browser console tells me that my JSON data has been stored into 'window.json' and I don't know how to reference that within my application. If I hard code some test JSON data into my application and reference that instead of trying to call from MongoDB, then the data populates in my Angular Material Table without issue.

**Configuration**

I have an Express/Node application that is making the calls to MongoDB and providing the data via http calls. I have a separate Angular application that is attempting to make an http call to the Express/Node application to consume the JSON from MongoDB and display it in the Material Table. All applications and MongoDB are running local on my computer (Windows 10).
Versions of packages:

- Node 9.3.0
- TypeScript 2.6.2
- Express 4.16.2
- MongoDB Node Driver 2.2.33
- Angular 5.x

**Sample MongoDB Data in the Movies Collection**

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56918f5e24de1e0ce2dfccc3"),
        "title" : "Once Upon a Time in the West",
        "year" : 1968,
        "imdb" : "tt0064116",
        "type" : "movie"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56918f5e24de1e0ce2dfccc4"),
        "title" : "A Million Ways to Die in the West",
        "year" : 2014,
        "imdb" : "tt2557490",
        "type" : "movie"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56918f5e24de1e0ce2dfccc5"),
        "title" : "Wild Wild West",
        "year" : 1999,
        "imdb" : "tt0120891",
        "type" : "movie"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56918f5e24de1e0ce2dfccc6"),
        "title" : "West Side Story",
        "year" : 1961,
        "imdb" : "tt0055614",
        "type" : "movie"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56918f5e24de1e0ce2dfccc7"),
        "title" : "Slow West",
        "year" : 2015,
        "imdb" : "tt3205376",
        "type" : "movie"
}
```

**Angular Application (Front End)**

Note that the Angular application was created using the Angular CLI.

*app.module.ts*

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestService } from './services/test.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [TestService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*test.service.ts*

The "serviceUrl" path provides an array of data from MongoDB by using the following code in the back end Express application:

> let movieResults = await db.collection("movies").find().toArray();
>
> return movieResults;

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Movie } from '../models/movie.model';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  private serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/moviesdb';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTest(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.serviceUrl);
  }
}
```

*movie.model.ts*

```js
export interface Movie {
  title: string;
  year: number;
  imdb: string;
  type: string;
}
```

*app.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { Movie } from './models/movie.model';
import { TestService } from './services/test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'My App';
  displayedColumns = ['title', 'year', 'imdb', 'type'];
  
  movies: Movie[];
  dataSource = new TestDataSource(this._testService);

  constructor(private _testService: TestService) {}
  
  ngOnInit(){}
}

export class TestDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private _testService: TestService) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this._testService.getTest();
  }
  disconnect() {}
}
```

*app.component.html*

```js
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1 id="title">
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <h2>Here are some movies you may be interested in:</h2>
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Title Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let movie"> {{movie.title}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Year Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="year">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Year </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let movie"> {{movie.year}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- IMDB Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="imdb">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> IMDB </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let movie"> {{movie.imdb}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Type Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let movie"> {{movie.type}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

**Articles Referenced**

- [getting angular material table to work properly with api call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829160/getting-angular-material-table-to-work-properly-with-api-call)
- [Properly display JSON in table angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235382/properly-display-json-in-table-angular)
- [How to pass json data received from service to an array in component in angular material for angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47550532/how-to-pass-json-data-received-from-service-to-an-array-in-component-in-angular)
- [Developing Node.js Apps Using TypeScript and MongoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iFghvFs4AY)

Many thanks in advance for any guidance that you can provide!

Comment: You may want to look at the various posts in Stack Overflow regarding Mat Table and Firebase.

Comment: Try to produce a minimum code so that user will read your question, I dont think this long question will be read by anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation @AniruddhaDas. I'll reformat the question for the minimum code. I was trying to be as thorough as possible before to ensure that follow-up questions would not be required.
Can someone tell me if posting a public repository on Github would be a preferred method for longer examples, or is it best to simply keep everything contained within the Stack Overflow post?

Comment: Yes. I think GitHub link will be fine

Answer (score 1):

Material table component use "dataSource" variable so you need to use "datasource" in service response with OnInit.

An Example:

```
ngOnInit() {
this._humanService.getHumans().subscribe(
  resp => {
    this.dataSource  = new MatTableDataSource(resp);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

}